# Why is Seq.chunkBySize is not recognized

Tags: f#

I am not sure why the following statement has an error:

```
let grid = [ for i in 0..8 -> (i, true) ] |> Map.ofSeq
let chunked = grid |> Seq.chunkBySize 3
```

**Error:**

> Seq.chunkBySize is not recognized.

My F# runtime is pointing to

> 4.3.1.0

.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Seq.chunkBySize` was added in F# 4.0  It requires FSharp.Core 4.4.0.0.

See this page for additional information: https://fsharp.github.io/2015/04/18/fsharp-core-notes.html

Comment: @ScottNimrod I think you'll probably need to install VS2015.

Comment: @ScottNimrod Maybe check the reference to FSharp.Core in your project and see which version it points to.  If it's 4.3.1.0, delete the reference and then add a new reference to FSharp.Core from the list of assemblies.  Hopefully 4.4.0.0 will be visible in that list.